# Store string values to array inside a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to store all the values of `text` inside an array in a loop, is it possbile? can someone give me a hint on how to do this?

```
  $('#wa li').each(function (i) {

    var text = $(this).text();

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) – there's no need for intermediate variables or loops

```js
const liTexts = 
  $ ('#wa li')
    .map ((idx,elem) => $(elem).text ())
    .get ()
    
console.log (liTexts)
// [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="wa">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Man, other people are the worst, am I right? (Kidding. And I agree that `.map()` is the way to go here.)

Comment: for a second I thought you had `map`'s callback incorrect, before I checked jquery's documentation and realized their api is just backwards.  Also, nice to meet you @nnnnnn

Comment: @aaaaaa, ya, jquery is the new php

Comment: @aaaaaa - Likewise. I don't *know*, but I suspect it is backwards because you can use `this` to refer to the element, so then if you want the index too you can just define that one argument in your callback.

Comment: no api should be built around `this`, which I swear accounts for half of all js stack overflow questions

Comment: @aaaaaa - 20% `this`, 20% closures, 20% typos, 20% didn't read easily accessible documentation, 20% code this for me. (OK, I shouldn't have said 100%, there *are* good, non-duplicate questions too.)

Comment: i should change my name to *vvvvvv*

Comment: Not kkkkkk? My real name starts and ends with "n". My sister's name is Naomi.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArr = []; // define the array
$('#wa li').each(function (i) {
  myArr.push($(this).text()); // push the value into the array
});
console.log(myArr); // ['hello', 'world', ...] use the array
```

Answer (score 2):

You can  use **`array.push()`** to the values to the array

```
var myArr = []; // define the array
$('#wa li').each(function (i) {
  myArr.push($(this).text()); 
});
```